# Pandas read_excel

Tags: python, pandas

I struggled for a few hours how to read an excel file with pd.read_excel where the path is a website address. I figured out that the link doesn't go directly to the file but just triggers downloading. Is there any easy way to solve it?

Part of code:

```
link_energy = 'http://unstats.un.org/unsd/environment/excel_file_tables/2013/Energy%20Indicators.xls'
df_energy = pd.read_excel(link_energy)
```

Error message:

```
XLRDError: Unsupported format, or corrupt file: Expected BOF record; found b'\n\n\n<!DOC'
```

Probably it's not a problem of pandas but my lack of skills how do do it.

Comment: can you post the full url to the xslx file?

Comment: also, please check if the above post resolves your problem.

Comment: ok, I added full url but, comes form a platform coursera. Does't it explain anything?

Comment: I saw it and checked it @jp_data_analysis, it's not the case here

Comment: now it should be possible to check the file

Answer (score 1):

For me works everything as expected in the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
link_energy = 'http://unstats.un.org/unsd/environment/excel_file_tables/2013/Energy%20Indicators.xls'
df_energy = pd.read_excel(link_energy)
df_energy
```

without errors on the following env:

The version of the notebook server is: 5.2.2
The server is running on this version of Python:

Python 3.6.3 | packaged by conda-forge | (default, Nov  4 2017, 10:10:56) 
[GCC 4.8.2 20140120 (Red Hat 4.8.2-15)]

Current Kernel Information:

Python 3.6.3 | packaged by conda-forge | (default, Nov  4 2017, 10:10:56) 
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 6.2.1 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

Comment: I can confirm, after updating pandas to the last version (don't know if it was needed) and installing xlrd (no need to import it), pd.read_excel works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

However I am not having access to your url posted.

but `pd.read_excel` won't work and you need to use `pd.read_csv`

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('https://cib.societegenerale.com/fileadmin/indices_feeds/CTA_Historical.xls')
```

Now you need to see the excel file what it contains what is the separator used, if there are any other values in any columns then it needs to be skipped in order to load and read useful data.

Comment: I added url which you can access. As I understand your answer would solve the problem if my case is really a .csv file